# Laravel 5.1 consuming soap wsdl service using controller and model

Tags: mysql, laravel, wsdl, laravel-5.1, soap-client

Currently I'm using php and nusoap and wanted to convert it to Laravel.

When creating the soap calls I use data out of a mysql database.

So I think I would need a model (to get my data) and a controller (to create request).

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper;
class SoapController extends Controller {
public function demo()
{
// Add a new service to the wrapper
    SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
       $service
       ->name('currency')
       ->wsdl('path/to/wsdl')
       ->trace(true);
       ->options(['user' => 'username', 'pass' => 'password']);
     });

// Using the added service
SoapWrapper::service('currency', function ($service) {
var_dump($service->getFunctions());
var_dump($service->call('Otherfunction'));
});
}
}
```

from [laravel-soap](https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap) I couldn't find a tutorial on how to send login parameters prior to any other request. In the example 'using the added service' I see the login credentials but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I got soap to work in Laravel 5.1

1. clean install laravel 5.1
2. install [artisaninweb/laravel-soap](https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap)
3. create a controller SoapController.php

   ```
   <?php
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   use Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper;
   class SoapController extends Controller {
   public function demo()
   {
   // Add a new service to the wrapper
       SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
          $service
          ->name('currency')
          ->wsdl('path/to/wsdl')
          ->trace(true);
        });
   $data = [
            'user' => 'username',
            'pass'   => 'password',
           ];
   // Using the added service
   SoapWrapper::service('currency', function ($service) use ($data) {

   var_dump($service->call('Login', [$data]));
   var_dump($service->call('Otherfunction'));
   });
   }
   }
   ```
4. Create a route in your routes.php

`Route::get('/demo', ['as' => 'demo', 'uses' => 'SoapController@demo']);`

*If requered you can also use the model extension as described [here](https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap#usage-as-model-extension)*