# Laravel Controller using Non-Database Model

Tags: laravel, soap, model, controller

I have seen examples where the controller seems to work with a $request as a parameter

> example:
>   https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-posting-javascript-to-controller-wont-work?page=1

I have seen examples where the CRUD methods of the controller are generated and one can define one route for many (CRUD?) methods

> Ex: Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');

I also saw the following regarding Laravel Models

> Ex: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers Specifying The Resource
>   Model If you are using route model binding and would like the resource
>   controller's methods to type-hint a model instance, you may use the
>   --model option when generating the controller  And this YT Video as well:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpVE5RfcuTQ

It seems that the command below would bind Model functions with Controller functions:

> ex: php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
>   --model=Photo

**Question: Does this command refer to the use of ONLY DB Models? If not, can I make my own Model (that does not depend upon the DB) for use with the Controllers in this fashion?**

I would like to do one with SOAP

> Ex:php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
>   --model=MySOAPPhoto

I found this information on a SOAP Model:

> https://github.com/antonio8101/laravel-soap-w

This one speaks of using a SOAP client:

> [Laravel 5.1 consuming soap wsdl service using controller and model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314045/laravel-5-1-consuming-soap-wsdl-service-using-controller-and-model)

**Question: For the SOAP Model above, how can one find all of the methonds that need to be defined? Do I need to write a method all() - for example?**
What methods should be implemented (or created) so that when working with the controller (as in below):

> Ex:php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
>   --model=MySOAPPhoto

(and have everything work)

Comment: if you are using "find all " what it is finding and from where - database?

Comment: As of now, I have not created a model yet. With Laravel, it seems like when one mentions the word "model" the automatic assumption is that it will be tied to a database table. I would like to use a model based on SOAP instead. I found an example where a SOAP model is being used here: https://github.com/antonio8101/laravel-soap-w  but I was not sure of the methods being used for this model. How can I find this out?

Comment: Yes you can use it no problem. It is just passing the model instance with it. But make sure whatever method you are willing to call over the model instance it should be exists in your model class. Otherwise undefined function error will be thrown by your application. Passing model to resource means it just creating instance of your model class and passing it as argument to respective function where it is used.

Comment: For more details check this https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResourceRegistrar.php#L73 this is the method ultimately gets called internally when we are registering resource route.